# Using fetch and curl and obtain same response

Tags: node.js, json, express, curl, fetch

Im implementing PayU API with node.js. This is the curl command example written in the docs for a basic product order

```
curl -X POST https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 3e5cac39-7e38-4139-8fd6-30adc06a61bd" \
-d '{
   "notifyUrl": "https://your.eshop.com/notify",
   "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
   "merchantPosId": "145227",
   "description": "RTV market",
   "currencyCode": "PLN",
   "totalAmount": "15000",
   "extOrderId":"crsexcncm1faxpdggcikeg",
   "buyer": {
     "email": "john.doe@example.com",
     "phone": "654111654",
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Doe",
     "language": "en"
            },
   "products": [
       {
           "name": "Wireless Mouse for Laptop",
           "unitPrice": "15000",
           "quantity": "1"
      }
   ]
}'
```

When the request is done using cURL I get this response

```
{"status":{"statusCode":"SUCCESS"},"redirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pay/?orderIdredirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pay/?orderId=JFMCLJKKB2200724GUEST000P01&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJvcmRlcklkIjoiSkZNQ0xKS0tCMjIwMDcyNEdVRVNUMDAwUDAxIiwicG9zSWQiOiJ6RGVubjhoTiIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQ0xJRU5UIl0sInBheWVyRW1haWwiOiJqb2huLmRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTU5NTY5ODg3OCwiaXNzIjoiUEFZVSIsImF1ZCI6ImFwaS1nYXRld2F5Iiwic3ViIjoiUGF5VSBzdWJqZWN0IiwianRpIjoiMDM1MmM3YjYtZjFhZi00MmViLTg3NjgtZTFhNmE1N2NmMTU1In0.kfdrD6fCuppnpnTXIZSaKe_ExkmaRe-m9aipxQq_Nm8","orderId":"JFMCLJKKB2200724GUEST000P01","extOrderId":"crsexcncm1faxpdggcikeg"}
```

But when I use fetch this is the response I get

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: Gunzip {
      _writeState: [Uint32Array],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      _hadError: false,
      bytesWritten: 0,
      _handle: [Zlib],
      _outBuffer: <Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 20 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 20 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 20 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 22 75 74 66 2d 38 ... 16334 more bytes>,
      _outOffset: 0,
      _chunkSize: 16384,
      _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
      _finishFlushFlag: 2,
      _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
      _info: undefined,
      _level: -1,
      _strategy: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://secure.payu.com/pay/?orderId=LLLDRCLTLC200724GUEST000P01&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJvcmRlcklkIjoiTExMRFJDTFRMQzIwMDcyNEdVRVNUMDAwUDAxIiwicG9zSWQiOiJ6RGVubjhoTiIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQ0xJRU5UIl0sInBheWVyRW1haWwiOiJqb2huLmRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTU5NTcwNTk4MCwiaXNzIjoiUEFZVSIsImF1ZCI6ImFwaS1nYXRld2F5Iiwic3ViIjoiUGF5VSBzdWJqZWN0IiwianRpIjoiMWFkZjBmYzMtMzM3OS00NDBlLTg4YmYtYThlYWY3NzQ3MjBjIn0.5JhtmSD4WnubTlVy1CnT2ezBju7shhO511y09ObPD8M',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 1
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the same response?  I need the redirectUri when using fetch but haven't found the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: The response has an invalid JSON and it does not depend on the header that you set for response. Check these properties and values

```"redirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pay/?orderIdredirectUri":"https://secure.payu.com/pay/?......```

Seems to have missed `", "` in the `orderIdredirectUri`

Comment: I think those properties you are asking me to check are part of the response I get from the cURL request , what I really need is to obtain that same response when using fetch from node, but the actual response I get is what you say is an invalid JSON, so I don't know how to parse it and get the redirectUri from it. Do you know what else can I do?

Comment: Can you show your node js code for CURL request?

Comment: I'm sending the cURL request from the command line, but this is my node-fetch request ```    const data = {
     "notifyUrl"...
    }
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer 3e5cac39-7e38-4139-8fd6-30adc06a61bd",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Length": "552"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    fetch("https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders/", options)
    .then((res: any) => console.log(res))```